# How can I return either a specific container widget, or nothing at all

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I am using the Dismissible widget for swiping within my application. However, I wish to reuse the swiping activity, without the ability for the user to swipe. The whole class is wrapped in the dismissible.

So the overall code looks something like this:

```
Dimissible(
   Row(
       Column(
         // random code
       ),
   ),
);
```

Whereas I want to be able to either have everything wrapped inside the dismissble, or not, without having to copy paste the entire code into a new class. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why you don't create you `Custom Widget` ??

Comment: How would I go about that. Either return the dismissible or instead null? Wouldn't that leave me with an exception?

Comment: ```Dismissible(
    MyWidget(),
);
...
StatelessWidget Mywidget(){
... //Your components here
}
```

Comment: Maybe I didn't get your problem, can you be more specific ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I return either a specific container widget, or nothing at all
>
> How would I go about that. Either return the dismissible or instead null? Wouldn't that leave me with an exception?

You can return a blank `Container()` or a `SizedBox()` widget (when you condition meets to return null).

Flutter will not throw an error then.